# check if an item has been selected in ListBox

Tags: delphi, listbox

I want to check if an item has been selected in ListBox when user click on label 
if i execute like that i got this error `list index out of bounds`

```
procedure TfrMain.Label15Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 saveDialog : TSaveDialog;
 FileContents: TStringStream;
 saveLine,Selected : String;
begin
 saveDialog := TSaveDialog.Create(self);
 saveDialog.Title := 'Save your text or word file';
 saveDialog.InitialDir := GetCurrentDir;
 saveDialog.Filter := 'text file|*.txt';
 saveDialog.DefaultExt := 'txt';
 saveDialog.FilterIndex := 1;

 Selected := ListBox1.Items.Strings[ListBox1.ItemIndex]; 

 if Selected <> '' then
 begin
  if saveDialog.Execute then
  begin
   FileContents := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
   FileContents.LoadFromFile(ListBox1.Items.Strings[ListBox1.ItemIndex]);
   FileContents.SaveToFile(saveDialog.Filename);
   ShowMessage('File : '+saveDialog.FileName)
  end
 else ShowMessage('Save file was not succesful');
  saveDialog.Free;
 end;
end;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code

```
if Selected then
```

will not compile because `Selected` is a string. I guess you were experimenting just before posting this.

All the same you error messages and the question title suggests that   `ListBox1.ItemIndex`  is equal to -1. Hence the list index out of bounds error.

You need to add a check that `ListBox1.ItemIndex` is not -1 before reading from the list box. `ItemIndex=-1` is the way you detect that no item is selected. Your code should therefore look like this:

```
.....
saveDialog.DefaultExt := 'txt';  
saveDialog.FilterIndex := 1; 
if ListBox1.ItemIndex <> -1 then
begin
.....
```

Comment: it is i tried many things to test `Selected` like `if Selected <> '' ` and ended up with that becasue i didn't know how to test it, anyway thanks

Answer (score 2):

This occurs if nothing is selected in the list box.

Try Using:

```
procedure TfrMain.Label15Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 saveDialog : TSaveDialog;
 FileContents: TStringStream;
 saveLine,Selected : String;
begin
 saveDialog := TSaveDialog.Create(self);
 saveDialog.Title := 'Save your text or word file';
 saveDialog.InitialDir := GetCurrentDir;
 saveDialog.Filter := 'text file|*.txt';
 saveDialog.DefaultExt := 'txt';
 saveDialog.FilterIndex := 1;

 if ListBox1.ItemIndex >= 0 then
 begin
  Selected := ListBox1.Items.Strings[ListBox1.ItemIndex]
  if saveDialog.Execute then
  begin
   FileContents := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
   FileContents.LoadFromFile(Selected);
   FileContents.SaveToFile(saveDialog.Filename);
   ShowMessage('File : '+saveDialog.FileName)
  end
 else ShowMessage('Save file was not succesful');
  saveDialog.Free;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: If you have mentioned my code is saying `if ListBox1.ItemIndex >= 0` (greater or EQUAL to 0) and as you know `ItemIndex` is of type `Integer` and there is no other integer value between -1 and 0, so `ItemIndex >= 0` is definitely equal to `ItemIndex > -1` ;)

Comment: But it's much harder to read, and isn't the way it's usually written. Posting code that's more difficult to read is never good, especially when you're posting it for someone who is obviously fairly new to the language.  You're right, though; technically it's not wrong, and I'll remove my comment. (Still have to give David the upvote, though. :)) What you wrote is the equivalent of writing `if (something = true) and (something <> false) then` - it's a redundant, needless test. `if ItemIndex > -1` is the same test, and is much clearer in meaning.

Comment: As you have mentioned in your first comment, `ItemIndex` is zero based so it would not be "harder to read" if you compare it to zero instead of -1. ;)

Comment: @David, why? `ItemIndex` can never be < -1, and `<>` is an extra character to type when `>` is the same test. Vahid, it *is* harder to read than a simple `> -1`. Compare `greater than minus one` to `greater than or equal to zero` - just read it out loud.

Comment: @ken What I want to say is *is it selected or not* which is a boolean, either or question. <>-1 or =-1 feels more decisive to me than >-1 which to me hints at a sliding scale. And what's the negation? <0? That feels weird. As you yourself state, it can never be <-1 so what contemplate that? Would be nice it we had nullable types here.

Comment: @avid, the negation is `= -1`. <g> I always read the code in my head; what's easier, `greater than -1` or `not equal to -1`? And there is a sliding scale, it's either equal to -1 or anything greater than -1. As **I** said, it can never be `< -1`, but `<>` contemplates it being so, not vice versa. I guess it's a "I say tomayto, you say tomahto" thing (which is probably true, considering you're in the UK and I'm in the US). :D